# I met this strange thing in MPI using fortran,MPI_Barrier can't work

Tags: fortran, mpi

Here is my simple code while I want to use MPI_BARRIER in my program.I think my code doesn't have error,since I already add the param ierror.

```
program main
use mpi
implicit none
integer :: myid, numprocs, rc,ierr,i
call MPI_INIT(ierr)
call MPI_COMM_RANK( MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr )
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,numprocs,ierr)
    print*,"iter 1"
    if(myid.eq.0) then
        print*,"running",myid
    else
        print*,"running",myid
    endif
    print*,"waiting",myid
    call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
    print*,"end"

call MPI_FINALIZE(rc)
end program main
```

While I try to run it using

```
 mpirun -np 2 ./test
```

There always has error like below

```
 iter 1
 running           0
 waiting           0
 iter 1

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x10392d579
#1  0x10392c945
#2  0x7fff90dc7b39

YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault: 11 (signal 11)
```

I'm using MPICH3.2 and gfortran.And the fortran file is f90.I really don't know how to solve it.Thank you for helping me.

Maybe there is something wrong with my MPICH or the way I compile the program.
Since I use Mac OS,I just get MPICH use

```
brew install gcc
brew install mpich
```

While I use this to compile

```
mpif90 -fc=gfortran test.f90 -o test
```

Comment: Where did you get MPICH? How did you install it?

Comment: i do not see any errors in my environment. double check you are using the very same `MPICH 3.2` in order to `mpif90` **and** `mpirun` and the right libraries are used by the binaries (`mpirun -np 2 ldd a.out` can help you figuring out)

Comment: @francescalus @Vladimir F I use `brew install MPICH` on my mac to install MPICH, `mpif90 -fc=gfortran test.f90 -o test` to compile and `mpirun -np 2 ./test` to run. So is it something wrong with my MPICH , since I can run other program right except this.

Comment: Recommendation is to build your own copy of Open MPI https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=osx#osx-bundled-ompi
See those instructions for isntance https://github.com/firemodels/fds/wiki/Installing-Open-MPI-on-OS-X#option-2-compiling-open-mpi-and-fds-yourself